# lme4::lmer - Transforming scaled coefficients back after fitting a linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

Due to convergence issues, I estimated a model using lme4::lmer() with scaled variables (mean = 0, sd = 1). For interpretation, it would be nice to obtain the unscaled estimates / standard errors of the corresponding model. Are there any best practices / practical tips for doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply divide the estimates by the SD of their predictor-variable. Same for the standard error:

```r
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
m2 <- lm(mpg ~ scale(hp), data = mtcars)

coef(m1)["hp"]
#>          hp 
#> -0.06822828
coef(m2)["scale(hp)"] / sd(mtcars$hp)
#>   scale(hp) 
#> -0.06822828
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>